# Line-height affecting background color

Tags: html, css

I've got lines of text inside a div that alternate background colors to make it easier to read. Each of these has a display: block; property so the background-color spans the entire width of the div.

However, this puts each line of text rather far apart. If I bring the lines closer with line-height, the background-color no longer covers the text appropriately.

Here's an image showing what's happening:
[image: Example]

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to get this to look like the original, minus the space between lines?

Edit: Here's a jfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/f8K3T/

Comment: Include the markup for these sections - should be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: Examples are worth 1752 words. Use jsFiddle or alike to show us some HTML + CSS.

Comment: Added a jfiddle to the above.

Comment: Why are you using <span> instead of <p>?

Comment: Semantically, `ul` and `li`s would seem like the best fit here...

Comment: @Connor <p> seems to have some undesirable effects for what I'm trying to do. It will at times combine lines or make the heights on the background colors not right. Is there a reason to ever use p over span or vice versa? I suppose I've always just preferred span, but I did try it on this particular bit of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explicit line breaks in your markup.

These have a non-zero height, hence the gaps.

I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zmA8N/

I think this is what you're after.

Comment: I didn't think about that being an issue after adding the display:block; Thanks for the fork!

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin-top and margin-bottom on the text elements to bring them closer together.
Also make sure that padding:0;

If you provide a sample of your css or a JS fiddle I can give exact values

Comment: I applied your suggestion to the jfiddle I added to my original post with no luck.

Comment: Yeah well as others have posted since the brs will cause issues with that. You still maybe could have used negative margins to make it work but removing the breaks is a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use the css property height: #px; on the div element instead, and not defining a line-height.

Comment: Height is already defined on the div element itself. I included a jfiddle in my original post so you could have a better look if you'd like.

Comment: the SPAN element is not capable of being a block layer, so the best bet is to make each line it's own div with the background-color and height attributes set in there.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `<br />` tags like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/f8K3T/1/)

If you want spacing between the lines, just add: `span{ margin-bottom: 3px; }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the reason would be you line height value is less than font size of the content.

for example:

```
p{
line height:34px
}
p[class]{
font-size:30px
}
```

This will give a line height of 4 `px`;